# Xcode show current time using image

Tags: xcode, image, time, clock

I make a simple clock in xcode.
For now i use a font to display hour and minutes, they are in two separate label.
How can i do for display image for time, if i don't want use a font but one image for every number?
For time i use this:

```
   [oreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Digital-7Mono" size:250]];
   NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
  dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"11"];
  NSString *currentTime = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate: today];
  self.oreLabel.text = currentTime;
  pollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kPollingInterval
                                                 target:self
                                              selector:@selector(pollTime)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES];
[today release];
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object might be helpful to you.  Maybe something like this:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] 
                        initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit
                                                     | NSMinuteCalendarUnit)
                                           fromDate:today];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];

UIImage *hourImage = [UIImage imageNamed:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hour%d", hour]];
```

Comment: `NSDate *dateNow = [NSDate date]; // this is all you have to do to get the current time`

Comment: Edited my answer to use the convenience method.